# Highlight warning message in makefile

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have some code looks like below in Makefile.

```
ifeq ($(COMPARISON_NODE_VERSION),-1)
$(warning Please update your nodejs version to $(ENV_NODE_VERSION), or it may cause unexpected error later.)
endif
```

is there any chance to change the color of msg, like yellow?

Answer (score 2):

Make cannot do that, but you can do it yourself if you want, by embedding color code sequences into the message text.  It might be kind of gross to look at in the makefile though (you have to use the actual codes: make doesn't do any translation of character codes).

Comment: embedding color code sequences into the message text , do u have example?

Comment: The question is , this msg should display before all tasks.

Comment: Functions that are not part of recipes are evaluated as the makefile is read in, so this warning will be printed when the makefile is parsed.  As for color codes, it depends on your terminal.  However most terminals support http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code codes.  Also you can use `tput` to generate some codes for you: see http://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/